# Can I use UPS to send my tax returns from abroad to IRS Austin?

Tags: income-tax, state-income-tax

I have used an online service to do my taxes and they have asked me to mail the signed returns along with my W2s and other documents to IRS at Austin and the treasury dept of New Jersey for the state returns.  I have moved to Italy and I was wondering if I can use UPS to send my tax returns.

Edit:

I permanently moved out of USA. I am filing as a non resident alien on the income I earned while I was in USA.

Edit: Maybe I should call IRS and ask them.

Answer (score 11):

From the [IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/filing/submission-processing-center-street-addresses-for-private-delivery-service-pds) -

```
Austin - Internal Revenue Submission Processing Center
3651 S IH35
Austin, TX 78741
```

You are not the first person needing to ship to IRS via Fed-Ex or other private carrier.

For [New Jersey](https://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/njit18.shtml), the shipping address is:

```
State of New Jersey
Division of Taxation
Revenue Processing Center
200 Woolverton Street
Building 20 
Trenton, NJ 08611
```

Comment: Joe: The address you give is from the section for those living in the US; there is a separate section for US citizens and tax residents living abroad, and that gives the _mailing_ address as Department of the Treasury Internal Revenue Service Austin, TX 73301-0215, USA, and doesn't mention sending the return via PDS (Private Delivery Services) such as FedEx and UPS etc at all. Maybe the IRS doesn't accept returns that come via PDS from abroad? On the positive side, those filing from abroad automatically have an extension till June 15 for filing, though tax owed must be paid by April 15.

Comment: @DilipSarwate  OP may well have been in the US for all relevant times in 2018 -- in which case he *should* be using the domestic address.   (Relevant times = times he earned any money).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking just, exactly.

Comment: I permanently moved out of USA. I am filing as a non resident alien on the income I earned while I was in USA.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - the address with the 9 digit zip is definitely a PO Box. I agree that the IRS site shows only the PO address for international returns, but I’d be confident the address would work.

Answer (score 2):

*Look* at the IRS address carefully. If it is a P.O. Box, or the address is merely "Internal Revenue Service, Austin TX nine-digit zipcode" then UPS will not work because UPS and FedEx and DHL etc need a *street address*, and cannot deliver to a P.O. Box or to the other form of address where the nine-digit zipcode is basically a P.O. Box number; the US Postal Service is going to put every piece of *mail* with that nine-digit zipcode into one P.O. Box (actually, deliver to the address that the IRS has set up instead of the IRS sending out its own courier in a van to get its mail from a physical Post Office Box located in a post office).  In such cases, your on-line program might tell you a street address that can be used for delivery via UPS etc, or if not, you can get the address from the IRS website.

For *domestic* deliveries of small packages that don't have *guaranteed* delivery dates, UPS seems to have a deal with the USPS that UPS will deliver the package to the local post office and then USPS will actually bring it to your home. Whether this allows a shipper to send a package via UPS to a P.O. Box or to a nine-digit zipcode that is essentially a P.O. Box is something I don't know. Whether this facility is available for international shipments via UPS is also something I don't know; the answer might by Yes in the first instance and No in the second, or No in both cases, or (most unlikely) Yes in both cases.

Comment: My tax prep software asked me to send my signed returns to a PO Box (Department of the Treasury
Internal Revenue Service Austin, TX 73301-0215, USA). From IRS website, https://www.irs.gov/filing/submission-processing-center-street-addresses-for-private-delivery-service-pds, I assume I can send to the IRS Austin address?

Comment: @Morpheus Errrr No. The IRS link that you provide says that private delivery services should use Internal Revenue Submission Processing Center
**3651 S IH35**, Austin TX 78741 and not what you have.  In the cryptic nomenclature used in Texas or maybe just around Austin, this most likely stands for 3651 South Interstate Highway 35 which is a street address. The physical location of the premises is _not_ on the Interstate Highway itself but on an access road that runs parallel to the Highway from exit to exit.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I am suggesting an alternative.  FreeFillableForms.com is endorsed by the IRS (https://www.irs.gov/e-file-providers/before-starting-free-file-fillable-forms) and allows you to e-file, which is the arguably fastest, safest way to get your return to the IRS (I am surprised your online service did not give you that option).  They have most forms available, but in case you need exotic ones, double check before your start.  Be aware that the IRS does some sanity checks on e-filed returns before accepting them, so you might get an e-mail a day after filing that your return was rejected because you forgot to check some box or left something blank.  In that case simply correct the issue and e-file again.  (I mention this so you allow a couple of days of buffer before the due date.)

Many states have similar online filing services, although some have restrictions with regard to the forms that are available (e.g. resident vs nonresident).

In your case the disadvantage is that you have to type in all the data from the forms you already have, so you are trading labor for cost savings and speed.

If you are worried about the speed of the postal service and your are expecting a refund (if you owe, the IRS might charge late fees and interest), you could also file an extension electronically (with minimal typing), so it won't matter if the return arrives a couple of days late.
EDIT: As @DilipSarwate mentioned, you have an automatic extension until June 15 anyway, so the above only applies if you needed more time than that.

Comment: That may not work.  E-"file" is not filing.  It is a mutual *agreement* to interchange data *in lieu of* filing -- and IRS will only agree if the data submitted conforms to certain norms and what the system expects.  If not, IRS will bounce it out and make you *file for real on paper*, to make you swear the data is accurate with an ink signature (so they can getcha if it's wrong).  That is what his system is telling him to do.  Your site would do the same, for the same reasns.

Comment: @Harper, I don't see anything in the question indicating what "his system is telling him to do" and the IRS heavily advertises "e-filing", since it saves them the cost and potential errors of manual data entry, so I doubt they would refuse a return that meets the sanity checks I mentioned.  That said, I believe most e-filing systems want you to verify your identity by entering information from last year's return, so you may not be able to use them for your first return, which may or may not be the case for the OP.

Comment: In the first sentence of OP.  Yes, IRS wants everyone to e-file *who can*.  Those sanity checks may be broader than you think.  Aside from cases too complex for automation (want to see "too complex for automation", check out the efforts to automate the 1023 form!) I am saying they may also reject in special areas of interest to IRS, e.g. areas where there is frequent fraud, where they really want a human to *sign a form* so they can't claim later it was a computer glitch.  Judges don't like computers.  They do like paper.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully filed Federal, NY and NJ taxes from overseas this year. I just went to my regular post office and posted them like I would any other normal international mail. It took around 2 months from posting to receiving my refund.

Federal:

```
Department of the Treasury
Internal Revenue Service
Austin, TX 73301-0215 USA
```

New Jersey:

```
State of New Jersey
Division of Taxation
Revenue Processing Center
P.O. Box 555
Trenton, NJ 08647-0555
```

New York:

```
State Processing Center
P.O. Box 61000
Albany, NY 12261-0001
```

Although you are not filing a NYS refund, I want to add this in case someone else who is filing NYS from overseas finds this answer. They may note that the first page of your NYS refund has this big scary message:

[image]

This message is pretty much rubbish. I have never once filed my NYS tax return electronically due to my wife not having a social security number, which immediately excludes you from e-filing. Also they do not allow e-filing when you have an overseas address. You can safely ignore this message.

Comment: So you used the _post office_ and its worked, But the OP wants to know about sending the tax return by UPS which the IRS includes in a category it calls PDS (Private Delivery Service). PDSs generally require a _street address_ to deliver; they can't deliver to a P.O. Box the way that the post office can.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I see. I didn't understand that from the question.