# Where to send my CP14 payment?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, payment

I received a CP14 notice. Where do I send my payment? The address I see is Internal Revenue Service, Austin TX 73301-010. Is this correct?

Comment: Isn't there a pre-addressed bill and envelope?

Comment: If you have a bank account (with the money in it) **you can pay electronically** using Direct Pay [on the website](https://www.irs.gov/payments), which has zero transaction cost (to you) and can't get delayed, lost, or misread. (You _can_ also pay from a debit or credit card, but that does have direct costs, and using CC for _any_ cash txn unless you pay it off immediately is a bad move, as discussed in numerous other Qs.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I was going to make that an answer, but https://www.irs.gov/payments/available-payment-types-for-irs-direct-pay doesn't list CP14.

Comment: @RonJohn: as long as you specify the correct tax type and period (what IRS calls a 'module') I'm almost certain it will work -- although I haven't tried it because I haven't run any delinquent balances in the past few years, and anyway I use EFTPS instead because I had already set that up about 15 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Most IRS collection centers are not an actual bricks-and-mortar IRS office but rather a P.O. Box without a P.O. Box number shown explicitly.  The P.O.Box number is essentially "hidden" in the last 4 (sometimes 5) digits of the *nine*-digit zipcode. So, to explicitly answer your question "Is this correct?", the answer is  is _No since you have shown only 8 of the 9 digits of the Austin TX zipcode. But if you write the zipcode correctly on the envelope in which you mail your check, you should be OK.

See *[this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/107210/5760)* and more especially the comments following the answers to the question for a discussion of this point.